# iPhone: play podcasts via voice command?

Tags: podcasts, iphone, voice-dictation

Is there a way to get the iPhone 3gs to play a Podcast via voice command?

I've tried all sorts of things and it doesn't seem to work. I believe the official answer is no, but I was wondering if there was a Cydia or other app that can achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "via voice command"?  Do you mean from *any application* (i.e., as an OS-wide function that preempts whatever else you're running)?  From the home screen?  Or just speaking the podcast name from within a dedicated podcast app?

Comment: Good question. I think I mean by any application, but what I had in mind when I asked it is via the iphone voice command control, which seems to basically power either the phone or ipod applications from what I can tell. The podcasts I want played are in the iPod, but I could move them if it would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official answer is No.

As of iOS 4, there is a simple workaround, however. You can just add a podcast to a playlist and speak "Play playlist *PlaylistName*".

Comment: Of course, creating a smart playlist makes it less of a headache, and you can call it whatever you like.